# beginner python: need help overwriting list values for easy game

Tags: python, list, function

I'm building my first tic-tac-toe game as a novice and having lots of errors in trying to replace the `#` in `real_board[]`. This is my first coding language so I'm convinced I've made some silly mistakes here. I'm sure there are better ways to achieve this so I'm open to all suggestions.

```
def display_board(board):
    print('--------')
    print('|'+board[7]+ '|' +board[8] +'|' +board[9]+'|')
    print('--------')
    print('|' +board[4]+ '|'+board[5]+'|' +board[6]+'|')
    print('--------')
    print('|' +board[1]+ '|'+board[2]+'|' +board[3]+'|')
    print('--------')

real_board=['#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#']

player_moves=int(input('choose a number from 1 to 9: '))
if (player_moves)<1 or (player_moves)>9:
    print('unacceptable range')
elif (player_moves)==1:
    real_board[1]=='X'
    print(display_board(real_board))
```

So far I get this output:

```
choose a number from 1 to 9: 1
--------
|#|#|#|
--------
|#|#|#|
--------
|#|#|#|
--------
None
```

I know I haven't accounted for numbers larger than 1 but I'm trying to get over this initial hurdle first.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: A couple notes: arrays start at 0, so use ```real_board[0]``` to access the top left box. Secondly, display_board prints the board, so don't call ```print(display_board())```, just use ```display_board()```.

Comment: you wrote `real_board[1]=='X'`, this is a comparison, not an assignment. replace `==` with `=`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the equality operator (`==`) not the assignment operator (`=`):

```
real_board[1]=='X'
```

should be:

```
real_board[1]='X'
```